# openSUSE: Switch from Tumbleweed to standard distribution?

Tags: linux, opensuse, linux-distributions

Is there a way to go back to the standard openSUSE distribution from Tumbleweed (the rolling release)? If so, how?

I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed, and I am pretty pleased with it. But because of occasional issues (stability problems, and some programs malfunctioning with newest updates), I would like to go back to the standard distribution.

I do not necessarily want to revert all packages to earlier versions (and my OS seems to be working nicely at the moment), just no longer get the updates from Tumbleweed, but the standard distribution when they become available. (Maybe it is as simple as changing the repositories to those of the standard distribution?)

I have done quite a few Google searches on the topic, but so far I haven't found anything relevant. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a better answer that not using tumbleweed.

1. Uninstall new version
2. Download and install the old version under http://download.opensuse.org/
3. Launch the Software Manager (Yast sw_single)
4. Find each package that malfunctions and then under **Actions** select **Lock** now the old version will not be upgraded unless you unlock them.

It maybe fine to revert some packages, but reverting them all generates too many security vulnerabilities.

This is one way of adding the original 13.2 repos back

```
zypper ar "http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/non-oss/" OpenSuse13-2-nonoss
zypper ar "http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/repo/oss/" OpenSuse13-2-oss
```

Open yast or yast2 and launch repository manager and enable these and disable the other ones.  Install and lock the packages you need to.  Then disable these and enable the old ones.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! This can be useful. And is there a way to just change the repositories - such that you don't revert the current packages, just download the new updates from the stable release when they become available? (I am going to edit my question to clarify what I want.)

Comment: @jciloa  I have added the command line functions to add the repos you want.